# Load FBX material data

Tags: c++, mesh, fbx

I have the following piece of C++ code which I use to load triangle vertices from an FBX file:

```
FbxNode *node = scene->GetRootNode()->GetChild(0);
FbxGeometryConverter fbx_converter(node->GetFbxManager());
fbx_converter.Triangulate(node->GetNodeAttribute(), true);
mesh = node->GetMesh();
int num_vertices = mesh->GetPolygonVertexCount();
FbxVector4 *fbx_vertices = mesh->GetControlPoints();
int *fbx_triangle_vertices = mesh->GetPolygonVertices();
double x, y, z;
vector<vertex> vertices;
for (int vertex_index = 0; vertex_index < num_vertices; ++vertex_index)
{
    int index = fbx_triangle_vertices[vertex_index];
    x = (double)fbx_vertices[index][0];
    y = (double)fbx_vertices[index][1];
    z = (double)fbx_vertices[index][2];
    vertices.push_back(vertex(vector3(x, y, z), material(color(1, 0.5, 0.5), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)));
}
```

Currently, I am only loading vertex coordinates from the file. Now I want to load the vertex's material data (instead of assigning it manually like I did in the code snippet using `material(color(1, 0.5, 0.5)...`).

I see that an `FbxNode` object has a `GetMaterial()` method, but I don't know how to obtain this data since I am working with fbx vertices which are `FbxVector4`s, not nodes.

Comment: You forgot to mention what library you're using.

Comment: @Pharap I am using the official FBX SDK available here: http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_105ED19A_9A5A_425E_BFD7_C1BBADA67AAB_htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems materials can be obtained from the node by `FbxNode::GetMaterial(int pIndex)` and `FbxNode::GetMaterialIndex(const char *pName)`.

This data should be stored  in the `node` you are reading, alongside the vector information, i.e. it is stored in the node and not bound to the vectors themselves.

Comment: I saw that the material is stored inside nodes, but I don't know how to obtain nodes; for example, I have a vertex, fbx_vertices[index]. How do I "convert" this to a node, i.e. if I read all nodes, how do I know which node corresponds to this vertex?

Comment: @Eutherpy You don't convert a vertex to a node, you acquire the vertices from a node. The file is loaded into a big [tree of nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9wGx.png), and you traverse the tree to find the other nodes.

Comment: Oh, I see. I found the scene->GetNode(node_index) method, is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: @Eutherpy The FbxScene consists of a tree of nodes, which means it has one root node and each node has a list of child nodes. I'm fairly certain that you're supposed to traverse the tree to discover all the data. See [the documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/) for an example on how to traverse the tree nodes.

Comment: I found a helpful example here: http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_29C09995_47A9_4B49_9535_2F6BDC5C4107_htm, it seems you have to do this manually. Thanks for your help!